# Trying to load web pages using NSURLSession

Tags: swift, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

When I'm trying to load web pages along with cookie values my server side code is not getting right cookie value. So I am trying to load it through `NSURLSession`. But the delegate methods are not getting called.

I load the web page using `NSURLSession`. Below is my code

```
let sessionConfig = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
let session = NSURLSession(configuration: sessionConfig, delegate: self, delegateQueue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) 
let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(URLRequest)
task.resume()


func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask, didResumeAtOffset fileOffset: Int64, expectedTotalBytes: Int64){
    print("Resumed : \(fileOffset)")
}

func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask, didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64){

    print("Download : \(totalBytesWritten) Expected : \(totalBytesExpectedToWrite)")
}

func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingToURL location: NSURL){
    ProgressHUD.dismiss()
    webPage.loadData(NSData(contentsOfURL: location)!, MIMEType: (downloadTask.response?.MIMEType)!, textEncodingName: (downloadTask.response?.textEncodingName)!, baseURL: (downloadTask.response?.URL)!)
}
```

I had added `NSURLSessionDelegate, NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate, NSURLSessionTaskDelegate, NSURLSessionDataDelegate`

But the delegate methods are not getting called.

Is there any other way to load webpages?

Please help

Comment: Have you set your view controller as the delegate?

Answer (score 1):

The delegate methods you implemented are for download tasks, but you're using a data task.  You need to implement the data task delegate methods.